# Passing Time data type's value from a table to a JSpinner

Tags: java, mysql, swing, datetime, netbeans

The java program contains a table which has two columns, *Time* & *Feed Amount*. The contents of the table is obtained from a database using the select query. I wanted to pass the specific Time value being clicked on the column *Time* to a JSpinner (mouse-click event). The JSpinner was customized to handle Time data types (HH:mm:ss format). I tried some methods but was unable to pass the value to the JSpinner and get the error `java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date`. I somehow understand the error, but dont know what methods to use. Codes used are shown below.

**EDIT**. **I was able to do it using getTime method. The intellisense was really helpful.**

**Mouse Event**

```
private void feedsched_tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
        try{
            int row = feedsched_table.getSelectedRow();
            String table_click=(feedsched_table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM feedingsched WHERE time='"+table_click+"'";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){

                // I GUESS THIS GIVES THE ERROR
                Object value = rs.getString("time"); // "time" is the column name from the database
                Date  date = (Date)value;
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String timeval = format.format(date); 
                time_spinner.setValue(timeval);

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

**Spinner's customized code**

```
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
time_spinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor te = new JSpinner.DateEditor(time_spinner, "HH:mm:ss");
time_spinner.setEditor(te);
getContentPane().add(time_spinner, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 150, 140, 30));
```

**Solution**

```
Object value = rs.getTime("time");
 time_spinner.setValue(value);
```

Comment: add e.printStackTrace(); to  feedsched_tableMouseClicked method catch and paste the full stack trace in here

Comment: I was able to pass it. Thanks for the suggestion, didn't know how to print messages on the stacktrace. I might need this later @AshrafulIslam

Comment: Maybe you will want to elaborate your learning into an answer for all to learn from in the future? That would be very much in the Stack Overflow spirit. You may also accept your own answer.